# Images not rendering in HTML on Django runserver, but HTML works in browser

Tags: python, html, css, django, image

Building a site with Django and my index.html page is not rendering images properly. The image loads up fine when I open the HTML file in the browser, but when I do `python manage.py runserver`from powershell the HTML page doesn't render any of the images.

The code is below-- why is it not rendering when running in the server but works when I open in browser?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>Q&A</head>
<body>
<h1><img src="c:/users/chris/desktop/logo.jpg"></img></h1>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django needs to know the location of the static content to server them.
Do the following:

1. Set the path for settings/STATIC_DIR to the place where you are storing your images
2. Provide a STATIC_URL which would appear to client
3. Pass the context_instance from your view code to the template
4. Use the url in the template {{STATIC_URL}}path_to_your_image_from_static_dir

Answer (score 0):

Probably because of the file notation not being supported.

Try using the `file://` URI scheme.

Answer (score 0):

Because your image source should be a URL not a file path.

You need to upload the image to the webserver and link to it's URL, like http://yourdomain.com/img/logo.jpg