# How to import jeditable onto a django template with ubuntu

Tags: jquery, django, jeditable

as per topic, I am new to web development and have issues trying to use jeditable in a Django template.

To be specific, I have copied jeditable.js into a local filepath.

It says /users/funnynode/doyourwork/jeditable.js

However when I try to add source on the django template it's not working

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually need to look into serving static files in django

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

You can also find an example over here [Images not rendering in HTML on Django runserver, but HTML works in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13020816/images-not-rendering-in-html-on-django-runserver-but-html-works-in-browser/13020912#13020912)